# How to detect when a payment has been made and redirect user to specific page?

Tags: php, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am creating my custom payment gateway for Coinbase Commerce API in php and I got status in response somewhat like status: completed after transaction has been completed.I can't figure out how to redirect user to another page after payment has been made..??

**SO scenario is:**

User pays for amount he/she wishes for..First  status changes to new and after that goes to pending state.if everything goes well then finally completed..my concern is, what if it took 15 minutes to complete the payment, then how do I know It, how to redirect user when payment has been made and show him that some page that resembles payment has been made by you..

**Response:**

```
"timeline": [
            {
                "status": "NEW",
                "time": "2019-07-12T09:36:51Z"
            },
            {
                "payment": {
                    "network": "ethereum",
                    "transaction_id": "0x5e732333d4f6dabedd4a170796620af70f4391317f1bc1f5c2018fce0b17afff"
                },
                "status": "PENDING",
                "time": "2019-07-12T09:46:54Z"
            },
            {
                "payment": {
                    "network": "ethereum",
                    "transaction_id": "0x5e732333d4f6dabedd4a170796620af70f4391317f1bc1f5c2018fce0b17afff"
                },
                "status": "COMPLETED",
                "time": "2019-07-12T09:47:49Z"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

On your [Coinbase settings](https://commerce.coinbase.com/dashboard/settings) page, you can set a webhook url. Coinbase will let you know whenever a payment status changes. For example when the payment went though or whenever it was cancelled. Via that you can do some database stuff. In your case i would make it wait for a server response and whenever it received that, redirect the user to the page you wish them to go.

For more information about how to create and use the webhook i would refer you to [here](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-commerce-php/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanx for replying..when user pays money and what if it took payment to done 15 minutes time...how would I know it had done or what you are trying to say is if I set a webhook notification.can it automatically redirects when a payment has been made.ps: i am using coinbase API not their payment gateway UI..

Comment: do I have to refresh the page to perform the actions after payments has done .?

Comment: You could use javascript to check if the payment was successfull. What you could do is make a API, and make your javascript send the transaction ID to the api lets say every minute. And whenever the transaction went through you could make that API return something which redirects the user to the "Successful payment" page

Comment: Using webhooks is the way that I did it, you can include some system metadata in the transaction which will be relayed back to you when the transaction has been completed. When a certain script is called from the webhook, you can take the metadata and make changes on your system to indicate payment received.